# return rows dosn't have specefic number of length in pandas

Tags: pandas, string, extract, rows

am clean my dataset and cleaned it but am stuck in some rows don't have the specific length must have in the column
The column (order_id) must have 16 character the column type is object, so i'dont know how i can extract all rows don't have the exact character must be in column and how to remove those rows
Thank You .

[image: my dataset image in excel]

for more information
[image of column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGPVE.png)

in excel i can just filter the column and show only value that has 16 character
i want to do that in pandas i want just to return rows that contain 16 character and drop all row greater or lower than 16 character .

Comment: Please replace your image by a sample in a plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to keep all rows which match this pattern `[0-9A-F]{16}`:

```
df = df[df['order_id'].str.contains(r'^[0-9A-F]{16}$')]
```

Comment: i try this code but doesn't remove the rows that doesnt match 16 characters

Comment: Are you sure you don't have leading/trailing whitespaces?

Comment: yes because i using excel to check the dataset is change or not